# Stored Procedure inside a BackgroundService Timer

Tags: entity-framework, stored-procedures, .net-core, background-service

i want to have a stored procedure that run evrey 5 seconds with .net core 3.0.

i have been using a BackgroundService and when i try to call a stored proc, i get 'The thread 0xcec has exited with code'

```
{
public class ImportScope : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly BlockContext _context;
    private readonly ILogger<ImportScope> _logger;
    private Timer timer;
    private readonly IServiceScopeFactory _scopeFactory;

    public ImportScope(ILogger<ImportScope> logger, IServiceScopeFactory scopeFactory)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _scopeFactory = scopeFactory;
    }

    protected override Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        var scope = _scopeFactory.CreateScope();
        var blockContext = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<BlockContext>();
        timer = new Timer(o => blockContext.CourseExtentions.FromSqlRaw("exec stored_proc_wanted")) , null, TimeSpan.Zero, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your Timer implementation, I'm guessing the first parameter is the expression you want to execute. The first consideration is that DbContexts are not thread safe so they should be instantiated and disposed in the thread they are executing within.

For readability I'd create a function for the execution of the stored procedure, including the scoping for the DbContext:

```
private void execSproc()
{
    using (var scope = _scopeFactory.CreateScope())
    {
        using (var blockContext = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<BlockContext>())
        {
            blockContext.CourseExtentions.FromSqlRaw("exec stored_proc_wanted");
        }
   }
}
```

Then in your timer task method:

```
protected override Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
{
    timer = new Timer(o => execSproc , null, TimeSpan.Zero, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
    return Task.CompletedTask; 
}
```

This is assuming that your Scope is implementing IDisposable which most DbContextScope / Unit of Work patterns should be. Ultimately the DbContext needs to be scoped within the thread spun up on the timer task. I'm not sure what `Task.CompletedTask` is meant to represent in relation to the timer.

I would also recommend removing:

```
private readonly BlockContext _context;
```

since this isn't an injected member if the pattern is to use a ContextScope / UoW (`IServiceScopeFactory`) The purpose of this pattern is to provide a scope around a DbContext so you shouldn't ever be hanging onto a reference to a DbContext.